# How to apply CSS transition effect on a JS triggered event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm new to HTML/CSS/JS.

I have an HTML form with two input fields: e-mail and favorite website. I have two regular expressions in my JS file which check the input. This works fine, but I want to trigger an error message when the user clicks out of the box(`onblur` event).

My problem is that I want to apply a transition effect on the error, so it becomes visible over time, not just suddenly appears. Plus, right now, the error message pops up only once.

So my questions are:

1. How to apply the transition effect on the error message;
2. How to make it appear as many times as the user fails to enter the right input.

Here is my the HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS2_2.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="webpagevalidationerror" class="error">
        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        <p>Wrong website !</p>
    </div>


    <div id="emailvalidationerror" class="error">
        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        <p>Wrong e-mail !</p>
    </div>

    <form name="myform" class = "relative">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>

            E-mail :<br>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" onblur="validateEmail(this)"><br>

            Favorite website :<br>
            <input id="webpage" type="text" name="webpage" onblur="validateWebpage(this)"><br><br>

            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script src="JS_2.js"></script>

</body>
```

And the CSS file :

```
fieldset { 
    display: inline;
}

form.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 16px;
    width: 150px;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    top: 130px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    /*transition: 2s; How to apply this transition for the .triggered attributes ?
    transition-timing-function: linear;*/ 
}

.triggered {
    display: block;
}

.closebtn {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

And the Javascript file :

```
var emailerror = document.getElementById("emailvalidationerror");
var webpageerror = document.getElementById("webpagevalidationerror");

function validateEmail(email) {

    var re = new RegExp("^[^@]+@yahoo.com$");
    var re2 = new RegExp("^[^@]+@gmail.com$");

    if (!(re.test(email.value)) && !(re2.test(email.value)) || email.value == "") {
        emailerror.classList.toggle("triggered");
    }
}

function validateWebpage(webpage) {

    var re = new RegExp("^www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+$");

    if (!(re.test(webpage.value)) || webpage.value == "") {
        webpageerror.classList.toggle("triggered");
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `setAttribute` ?

Comment: If you mean to change this line :
emailerror.classList.toggle("triggered");
to this line :
emailerror.setAttribute("class","triggered");
then no, it's still not working.

Comment: please post some error which could help us to identify your problem else try to debug your code\

Comment: There are no errors, i just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate from `display:none` to `display:block`. The trick is to set scale and opacity to 0, then trigger the opacity animation with the delay of the scale animation duration.

Also validation functions may return  a boolean, to check if everything is ok when you submit your form (and you don't want to toggle `triggered` class, as you wish the message to be still displayed as long as the input is wrong. So just add class if it's wrong, remove it if it's ok).
And rather than set inline atributes on your HTML elements (onClick,onBlur,...), set eventlisteners in your js code (to avoid to mix js and html)

Here a working snippet adapted from your existing code:

```js
var emailerror = document.getElementById("emailvalidationerror");
var webpageerror = document.getElementById("webpagevalidationerror");
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
// loop throught closeBtn nodelist to add listener for each buttons
for(var i = 0; i < closeBtn.length; i++)
{
  closeBtn[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
   e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.remove("triggered");
   });
}

document.getElementById("webpage").addEventListener("blur",validateWebpage);
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("blur",validateEmail);
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",submitForm);

function validateEmail() {
    var valToTest = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var re = new RegExp("^[^@]+@yahoo.com$");
    var re2 = new RegExp("^[^@]+@gmail.com$");

    if (!(re.test(valToTest)) && !(re2.test(valToTest)) || valToTest == "") {
        emailerror.classList.add("triggered");
        return false;
    }
   emailerror.classList.remove("triggered");
    return true;
}

function validateWebpage() {
    var valToTest = document.getElementById("webpage").value;

    var re = new RegExp("^www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+$");

    if (!(re.test(valToTest)) || valToTest == "") {
        webpageerror.classList.add("triggered");
         return false;
    }
    webpageerror.classList.remove("triggered");
    return true;
}


function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();  
  var emailOk = validateEmail();
  var webPageOk = validateWebpage();
  if(emailOk && webPageOk){
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
  }
    
}
```

```css
fieldset { 
    display: inline;
}

form.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 16px;
    width: 150px;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    top: 130px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
   /* display: none;*/
    /*transition: 2s; How to apply this transition for the .triggered attributes ?
    transition-timing-function: linear;*/ 
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    transform:scale(0);
    opacity:0;
    transition: transform .2s, opacity 2s .2s;
    
}

.triggered {
   /* display: block;*/
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;  
}

.closebtn {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="webpagevalidationerror" class="error">
        <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
        <p>Wrong website !</p>
    </div>


    <div id="emailvalidationerror" class="error">
        <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
        <p>Wrong e-mail !</p>
    </div>

    <form id="myform" class = "relative">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>

            E-mail :<br>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email"><br>

            Favorite website :<br>
            <input id="webpage" type="text" name="webpage"><br><br>

            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort !

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show it smoothly just change your triggered class 
This will add a transition effect while adding the class to display it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ycLn2fyb/25/

HTML and javascript

```
<div id="webpagevalidationerror" class="error">
        <span class="closebtn" >&times;</span>
        <p>Wrong website !</p>
</div>

<button onClick="myFunction()"> TEST BUTTON</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var webpageerror = document.getElementById("webpagevalidationerror");


function myFunction()
{
    webpageerror.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Css:

```
div {
  position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    top: 130px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}


p {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 16px;
    width: 150px;
}

.closebtn {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: So I have updated my answer and have attached a jsfiddle also so that you would be able to see it in action.  

Just to make a difference I have used show class instead of triggered.

Comment: Yes it works now, thanks, someone also mentioned that the opacity is the key, but thank you for your effort too.